# How to stop a YouTube process running in Chrome?

Tags: video, google-chrome, youtube, macos

I have many tabs open in Chrome, and when I reboot it starts opening all the previous tabs, and when they contain YouTube videos they all start playing.

How can I find which tabs are running YouTube, so that I can pause them?

In the process list, there is no trace of YouTube, since it is running inside the browser, and only the tabs related processes are visible.

After reboot, it can happen that I have a YouTube process running and no corresponding tab from which to view it (I can just hear the audio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open **Task Manager**, under *Window* on the Chrome.app menu bar, and see a list of all running processes inside Google Chrome.

You can see **Task Name, Memory, CPU, Network** and **Process ID** for each task running at the moment.

At the bottom of the Task Manager Window you can end the Task you selected by pressing *End Process*.

[EDIT]

If you are on Windows the **Task Manager** window is accessible via the `Shift + Esc` shortcut.

Comment: If you run Chrome on Windows you can do the same with **Shift + Esc**

Comment: And this is an Apple Stack Exchange community. So I don't see why my answer deserves a down vote for being a *Mac Only* answer.

Comment: I think people think your reference to **Task Manager** is a reference to the Windows OS task manager, but it's actually talking about Chrome's built-in task list window. This answer is excellent. I don't know why it's getting down voted. But have an upvote from me.

Comment: @IanC. Oh ok, I did't know there was a *Task Manager* on windows, at least not with that name. Thanks for your vote ;)

Comment: Thank you. A detail: is it normal that clicking on a single YouTube task, all the other YouTube tasks are selected as well? It looks like a YouTube task is a thread of the same unique process...

Comment: @Pietro that doesn't happen with me, can you send a screenshot please? Each tab on Google Chrome is a distinct process.

Comment: @dordio: I think the reason is that I have a lot of tabs opened, so when this is the case Chrome does not create a single process for each tab any longer, but starts using threads. In my case I have some tabs which can be selected individually, others which are grouped in clusters of three, four tabs (not related to each other by their contents). These share the same process ID. The fact that YouTube tabs are all grouped in the same process makes me think that this is not coincidental.

Comment: @Pietro that's beyond my knowledge of the issue. Maybe it's possible yes, that after clogging the available processes threshold it starts to thread each process with the next one. Did my answer solved what you were looking for?